# Powershell - Azure Storage Accounts - Get Last Authentication Time/Date

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage-account

Trying to get a list of storage accounts which are not in use. I've tried to go down the LastModified route but there are a couple of issues, first this only works with Blob storage, second if the container is a named with a dollar sign (e.g. $web) Get-AzStorageBlob errors out.

Is anyone aware of a better way of achieving this? I'm thinking if I could list when the Storage Account was last authenticated against it could give me what I'm after, but am drawing a blank when trying.

Answer (score 1):

I had been using the below logic and was been sucessfull in meeting a similar requirement.

**Logic :**

You could basically iterate through each Storage Account, find each container within them, sort them based on the last modified date (descending) - pick the topmost - check whether it is more than 90 (any number of days as per your requirement) days. If yes, go ahead and remove them.

**Snippet Code :**

```
#Setting the AzContext for the required subscription
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "<YOUR SUBSCRIPTION ID>"

#Going through every storage account in the mentioned Subscription
foreach ($storageAccount in Get-AzStorageAccount) 
{

#Storing the Account Name and Resource Group name which will be used in the below steps
$storageAccountName = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
$resourceGroupName = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName


# Getting the storage Account Key - it could be any 1 of the key. Taken the first key for instance. 
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName).Value[0]

# Create storage account context using above key
$storagecontext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

#Gets  all the Storage Container within the Storage Account
#Sorts them in descending order based on the LastModified
#Picks the Topmost or most recently modified date
$lastModified = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $storagecontext | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = {$_.LastModified.DateTime}} | Select-Object -Last 1 -ExpandProperty LastModified

# Remove storage account if it is has not been in past 90 days

    if ($lastModified.DateTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)) 
    {
        Remove-AzStorageAccount -Name $storageAccountName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Force
    }
}
```

The code was referenced from this  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64201817/find-unused-storage-account-azure-arm).

**Note :**

[Get-AzStorageContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/get-azstoragecontainer?view=azps-5.6.0)  - is not just specific to blob storage.

**Coming back to your other question :** -

*second if the container is a named with a dollar sign (e.g. $web) Get-AzStorageBlob errors out.*

This has been handled in the later version of Az.Storage. I would recommend you to upgrade the module and give it a shot. This has been discussed in this [thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/9897) The later versions of Az.Storage should be able to handle the Containers named "$web"

[image]

Comment: As it happens I was using this exact script for my LastModified attempt. The issue with the script I was finding, which is why I had to go down the Blob route, was because Last Modified on the Container isn't reflective of the contents of said container. LM on the container doesn't update if the Blobs within have been modified.

Comment: Can you pls confirm that you're using the latest Az.storage package ?

Comment: Yep

Script     3.4.0      Az.Storage

Comment: Any other ideas on this?